# Middleman Blog: How do I get a count of articles?

Tags: middleman

I'm trying to return a string of the total count of items in a Middleman blog. (I'm currently using 3 on a site).

The closest I've come to getting the count is including `= i` in a loop, in which the results went from 0 to 34. So I know one particular blog has 35 items but I can't get that value on its own.

It feels like I should be able to do something like:

```
def get_articles_count(blogName)
  data.blog(blogName).articles.count
end

= get_articles_count('posts')
```

Bonus begging: I'd love to know how I could've tracked down the answer, if possible. I'm missing something and I'd love to know where I should be looking. I've been referencing the local sitemap data http://localhost:4567/__middleman/sitemap, the MM docs, and the MM blog docs, but I can't decipher if an item in a blog is a page or an article. I only use article in my example because that's what the loops require for displaying post information.

It turns out that it's incredibly simple

```
= blog.articles.count
```

Comment: It turns out that it's incredibly simple
    = blog.articles.count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that it's so simple...

```
= blog.articles.count
```

Comment: You can accepg yor own answer. ^_^